# Generating four complementary intervals between 0 and 1

Tags: python, math

How do I generate a list that contains four tuples and each tuple is compose by two numbers between 0.0 and 1.0 following this rules:

- The first and the second number of each tuple cannot be the samecov
- The second number must be bigger than the first one
- The range cover by all four tuples must add 1
- The range covered by each tuple cannot have a intersection

`(0.01, 0.1), (0.1,0.2), (0.3,1), (0.2,0.29)` -> acceptable

`(0.1,0.2), (0.2,0.3) ,(0.2,0.3) ,(0.4,0.5)` -> repeated interval

`(0.1, 0.2), (0.30000000000000004, 0.5), (0.4, 0.8), (0.6, 0.9)` -> the range between the four tuples not add to 1 or 100%

So far I code this logic but I'm not respecting the condition  for the ranges to be complementary

```
interval_range = range(0, 100, 10)
interval = [
    (lowerlimit, upperlimit)
    for lowerlimit, upperlimit in product(interval_range, interval_range)
    if lowerlimit < upperlimit
]

interval_final = []
for one, two, three, four in product(interval, interval, interval, interval):
    size = one + two + three + four
    size_no_dup = set(size)
    if sum([one[1]-one[0],two[1]-two[0],three[1]-three[0],four[1]-four[0]]) == 100 and len(size) == len(size_no_dup):
        interval_final.append((one, two, three, four))
        break #just to see if the logic is working
```

Comment: Can you give examples of results that the code produces that break your rules?

Comment: Trying to find numbers that sum to *exactly* 1 is a hopeless task when you're dealing with floating point - you show one example of a number that is visibly different from its proper value, but in fact NONE of your numbers (other than 0.5) can be exactly represented as a float.  One fix would be to deal with integers only, representing hundredths or some such subdivision of your total value.  Finding four integers that sum to 100 is no problem.

Comment: @slothrop this one (0.1, 0.2), (0.30000000000000004, 0.5), (0.4, 0.8), (0.6, 0.9)

Comment: @jasonharper I can use int that to between 1 and 100

Comment: i have edited the question for clarification

Comment: @Gabriel Padilha Got it, thanks - so @jasonharper's comment covers that.  You could also consider using the `decimal.Decimal` class rather than floating-point numbers.

Comment: @slothrop i changed the question a little bit for clarification. The problem is not the float i can limit the choices of number to integers between 0 and 100. I have almost cracked the problem but the overlap between the ranges of the numbers in the tuples is still happening

Comment: There are a few ways to solve that: the one that's easiest to incorporate in your code is to check that `one[1] <= two[0]` (and so on).  Not necessarily the most efficient, but it depends how much of an issue performance is.

Comment: Actually - this can be simpler I think. If (a) all numbers must be between 0.0 and 1.0 and (b) the total "width" of all four ranges must be 1.0, and (c) they can't intersect: then the solution will always look like: `[(0.0, x), (x, y), (y, z), (z, 1.0)]` where `0.0 < x < y < z < 1.0`.  So pick three random numbers between 0.0 and 1.0, sort them, and you've got your x, y and z.

Comment: However, I might be missing something since I don't see why `(0.01, 0.1), (0.1,0.2), (0.3,1), (0.2,0.29)` is acceptable.  Don't the ranges covered there add up to 0.98 and not to 1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, this solution uses ints from 0 to 100 rather than floats, and gives non-overlapping ranges whose widths sum to 100.

This uses `itertools.pairwise` which is new in Python 3.10.

```
import random
import itertools

cuts = random.sample(range(1, 100), k=3)  # 3 guaranteed different random numbers from 1 to 99 inclusive
ranges = list(itertools.pairwise([0] + sorted(cuts) + [100]))
print(ranges)
```

Example output:

```
[(0, 11), (11, 63), (63, 72), (72, 100)]
```

If you want multiple combinations, you can wrap this in a `for` loop.  If you want to reproducibly generate the same series of solutions, set `random.seed` to a fixed value.

For earlier versions of Python 3, an alternative is:

```
import random

cuts = random.sample(range(1, 100), k=3)
points = [0] + sorted(cuts) + [100]
ranges = [(points[i], points[i+1]) for i in range(len(points)-1)]
print(ranges)
```

To enumerate every valid combination:

```
valid = []
for x in range(1, 98):
    for y in range(x+1, 99):
        for z in range(y+1, 100):
            valid.append([(0, x), (x, y), (y, z), (z, 100)])
print(len(valid))
print(valid[0])
print(valid[-1])
```

prints:

```
156849
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 100)]
[(0, 97), (97, 98), (98, 99), (99, 100)]
```

Comment: can you tell me a way to do that in the for loop and cover all the possible values? for the for tuples?

Comment: Sure - see the edited answer!